# Django Jwt Authentication on API Routes

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python world, I have experience with Laravel Framework and I am planning to create a web site in Python Django Framework. My only concern is that is it possible to have web and api routes, both in Django Framework. 
As in Laravel I was able to secure api routes with jwt authentication and web routes with normal login process.
Is it possible to do the same with Django or Not ?
if yes, can someone provide me a tutorial with web and api url routes.

Thanks,

Comment: While I can tell you that it is possible to do that just by using different decorators, asking for tutorials is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Just follow the main Django tutorial and after that, follow the Django rest Framework tutorial. It should be obvious how to